# time difference between datetime value SQLite C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a DateTime record in SQLite database.

```
time

11-08-2021 15:16:44
11-08-2021 17:09:22
11-09-2021 17:20:39
...
11-11-2021 09:31:54
11-11-2021 10:35:37
11-11-2021 10:45:11
11-11-2021 11:54:28
```

---

I filter the DateTime that fall in the specific date range by using

```
string date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:00Z");
string query = $"SELECT * FROM LastRun WHERE LastUpdateTime > '{queryDate}' ";
```

I able to get the results as below.

```
time

11-11-2021 09:31:54
11-11-2021 10:35:37
11-11-2021 10:45:11
11-11-2021 11:54:28
```

---

The next thing is I want to get the time difference among each other like below.

```
time                  difference (hour)

 11-11-2021 09:31:54   1
 11-11-2021 10:35:37   ??
 11-11-2021 10:45:11   ??
 11-11-2021 11:54:28   ??
```

Is it possible to get the time difference like this and how I query and get the difference of the time? Any suggestion?

**EDIT:**

Now I have a fix time span, which is '00:10:00'. I want to make a compare between time difference that get before and this timespan. However, I get the wrong result since the value of '(thisDateTime - prev.Value)' becomes '00:00:00" when I try to insert the value. Please look at this pic ([Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8wOA.png)). So, all the result that return becomes '1'.

```
    while(reader.Read())
   {
     ......
      prev = thisDateTime;
         TimeSpan fixTimeDiff = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
         //Console.WriteLine(fixTimeDiff);
         var d = thisDateTime - prev.Value;
         int compare = TimeSpan.Compare(fixTimeDiff, d);
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} ( Compare should return {3} )", 
         fixTimeDiff, compare == 1 ? ">" : compare == 0 ? "=" : "<", d, 
         compare);
    }
```

Comment: AIUI, SQLite doesn't have an intrinsic column type for a datetime, so I guess these are strings. Not sure how your dd-MM-yyyy > '{yyyy-MM-dd}' worked.. SQLite does however, understand LAG and LEAD which allow you to access "rows around your current row". As such you'd be looking at something of the form `24 * (datetime(x) - datetime(lag(x) over(order by x)))` for a difference in hours.. You don't necessarily need sqlite to do it; you can be `foreach`ing the results in C# and do a `(thisDateTime - lastDataTime).TotalHours`, then update `lastDateTime = thisDateTime` on every row loop

Comment: @CaiusJard Hi, thanks for reply. Let's say the result above is get with this piece of code.....                      
               SQLiteDataReader reader = commandReader.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                { DateTime thisDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]); 
                Console.WriteLine("thisDateTime" + thisDateTime );
                }  How I assigned another value which is 'lastDateTime' like you suggest '(thisDateTime - lastDateTime)' . I'm confuse since all the datetime is belongs to 'thisDateTime'? Any reference?

Comment: You do it at the end of the loop so that next time the loop runs it's the previous time. I'll make an example

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, I have a concern on this. I had edit the question, can you please have a look when you are available?

Comment: Youve put the `prev = thisDateTime;` before the code that does `thisDateTime - prev` so of course it will always return 0; by the time you do `a-b` a and b are the same value. `prev = thisDateTime;` must always be the very last thing you do in the looop

Comment: @CaiusJard Ohhhh right....Thanks for the advice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do this in the c# side:

```
DateTime? prev = null;

while(reader.Read()){
  DateTime thisDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]); 

  if(prev != null)
    Console.WriteLine("time diff is " + prev.Value - thisDateTime );


  prev = thisDateTime;
}
```

Prev will always lag behind the current date

Comment: Thank you so much with the explanation and example. I Appreciate it.

Comment: No problems; if it's the answer you end up using, click the grey check mark to turn it green. This lets people see from the dashboard that you're no longer looking for an answer. If you are still looking for a(different) answer, make some mention of what you need